# SAS: PROC IMPORT on a FILENAME SFTP fileref

Tags: sas

In SAS (9.4, if it matters) I would like to grab a CSV file from a remote host via SFTP, parse the CSV, and drop the result into a SAS data table.

I set up SFTP using PuTTY as described in the SAS docs. Binding a fileref to SFTP works okay, something like:

```
FILENAME mysftpfileref SFTP 'location/on/host/file.csv' HOST='myhost' USER='mysuser';
DATA _null_;
    INFILE mysftpfileref TRUNCOVER;
    INPUT a $25.;
RUN;
```

Will successfully read data.

However, I can't seem to figure out to use `PROC IMPORT` to actually parse the data. The docs for that proc state

> "The IMPORT procedure does not support device types or access methods
>   for the FILENAME statement except for DISK. For example, the IMPORT
>   procedure does not support the TEMP device type, which creates a
>   temporary external file."

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to either:

- Write the import code yourself (using the data step)
- Download the file in some fashion and then run `PROC IMPORT` on the downloaded file

If you choose the second option, you can do this a few ways.  The easiest is probably to write something like the above data step, read the entire line in or use the `_INFILE_` automatic variable, and then write it out locally.  Something along these lines (define these filenames or change them, of course):

```
data _null_;
 infile Sftpfile;
 file localf;
 input @;
 put _infile_;
run;
```

Comment: Good heavens. Thanks!